# google sheets if string matches and is last matching string in set of cells get value of cell nest to it

Tags: google-sheets

below is an example of the data in the table

```
+--------------+------+---------+   
| Expense Name | Cost | mileage |    
+--------------+------+---------+   
| Costco Gas   |   20 |  145200 |    
| marathon gas |    2 |  145500 |   
| oil change   |   35 |  145600 |   
| marathon gas |   25 |  145750 |   
| A/C Work     |  305 |  145800 |   
| oil change   |   36 |  150000 |   
+--------------+------+---------+
```

Whenever the "Expanse Name" string equals "oil change" and it has the highest Mileage from the corresponding mileage I want that mileage to appear in a separate column.

So with this data I would search through the "Expense Name" column and find two that matched the string. From those two I want the one with the higher mileage(150000) to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method that doesn't require dragging or array formulae is

```
=MAX(FILTER(C2:C, A2:A = "oil change"))
```

Answer (score 0):

let us say expense name is in `A1`.
In `D2` put the formula `=COUNTIF("oil change",A2)*C2`.
Grab the lower right hand corner handle of the cell and drag it down to copy throughout your data set (in your case `D7`).

One cell below (`D8` in your example), say `=MAX` of the above cells, so in your case `=MAX(D2:D7)`.
That cell contains your answer.

Comment: This can be aggregated into `=ArrayFormula(max((A2:A="oil change")*C2:C))`